# О современном понимании фразеологизма «без царя в голове»

Tags: фразеология, семантика

Я не часто слышу этот фразеологизм, но все-таки случается. Правда, понимала я его несколько иначе, чем это  обычно объясняется:  **глупый, несообразительный, несмышлёный человек.** Происхождение связано с пословицей «У каждого свой царь в голове», где разум в голове сопоставляется с царём в государстве.

**Вот у Гоголя:**  «Хлестаков, молодой человек лет двадцати трёх, тоненький, худенький; **несколько приглуповат** и, как говорят, без царя в голове — один из тех людей, которых в канцеляриях называют пустейшими. Говорит и действует без всякого соображения.

Но Хлестаков – не глуп, а приглуповат. В современном значении –  это вроде не что чтобы глупый, а неорганизованный человек, который не ведет business diary, а с утра не помнит, что он делал вчера и что будет делать сегодня.

Но даже такая трактовка меня не очень устраивает. Царя давно уже нет, и мне кажется, что  слово царь  в большей степени  символизирует уже не ум, а **подчиненность, отсутствие свободы, необходимость жить по чьей-то указке.**

А ваши знакомые употребляют это фразеологизм и что вы думаете о его современном значении?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

> Священник возглашает: «Слава Святей, и Единосущней, и Животворящей, и Нераздельней Троице всегда, ныне и присно и во веки  веков»... и  вместе с дьяконом поет: «Приидите, поклонимся Цареви нашему Богу» (канон Великого Четверга, песнь 4), «... Яко Твоя держава, и Твое есть Царство, и сила, и слава».

В притчах о Царстве Божьем Христос даёт Божественное Учение о распространении среди людей Царства Божия или Царства Небесного. Под этими именами следует понимать Церковь Христову на земле, которая вначале состояла из двенадцати Апостолов и ближайших учеников Христовых.

Современные православные, во многом «размышлительным» путём пришедшие к вере, только так и воспринимают человека (без царя в голове = без должной мудрости) как недостаточно разумной и несостоявшейся личности. А к цели, т.е. спасению, может привести только личный опыт, своя воля и трезвый ум.

Собственно таким же, но всякий раз в конкретной жизненной ситуации, является такой (без путеводителя, без принципов, без точки зрения) человек из общества: он не склонен строить долгосрочных планов и не задумывается о каких-либо последствиях своих действий.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос. Малое число выделенных мест безмерно радует.

Comment: Я вас поняла. Обязуюсь больше внимания уделять оформлению ответов.

Answer (score 2):

Лично я это выражение всегда понимал как отсутствие внутренней организованности, поведенческую неустойчивость, подверженность чужим отрицательным влияниям (именно отрицательным, поскольку для этого обычно не требуются внутренние усилия).
Получается почти противоположное вашему - у вас "царь в голове" означает "жить по чьей-то указке", у меня - "сопротивление чужому влиянию".
В пользу своего понимания замечу, что речь всё-таки о ВНУТРЕННЕМ царе. То есть о самодисциплине, которая только и может обеспечить свободу от внешнего. Как в государстве крепкая власть гарантирует собственную суверенность.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Но мне кажется, что уже во времена Гоголя имелась в виду именно внутренняя неорганизованность человека. Он же об этом говорит, описывая  характер Хлестакова.

Comment: @Sharon Я плюсую Сергея и не понимаю, почему вы считаете, что значение фразеологизма изменилось / должно измениться со времен Гоголя? Только потому, что царя уже нет?

Comment: Я так не считаю.  Но иногда  лично мне видится  в этом сочетании разный смысл. Если у человека странная логика и поведение (с моей точки зрения), то я готова сказать, что он без царя в голове. Но иногда мне кажется, что необходимость царя в голове - это навязывание мне авторитетов и стремление мною руководить, тогда я понимаю фразеологизм по-другому: внешнее руководство мне не нужно.